# Apply luminosity channel of original image over a greyscale copy with Pillow

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to use Pillow (PIL fork) to convert an image to greyscale and apply the pixel luminosity of the original image over it. I'm new to both Pillow and Python and am having difficulty with this. I tried using histogram data, the point function, etc., but most simply result in an increased contrast that I would get from calling ImageEnhance.Contrast(). Is there something simple that I'm missing or would this also require something like Numpy?

Thank you for any information you can provide.

Comment: *convert an image to greyscale and apply the pixel luminosity of the original image over it*.Why would you want to do that?If so,why do you want to convert it to greyscale?

Comment: Please give a link, reference or description of this technique and also sample input and output images to enable us to better assist you. Kindly also show your code. Thank you.

Comment: I want to make any artifacts pop without being distracted by the color. I'll get my code sample together and post it once I get back home. Thank you.